# "this" in function invocation javascript

Tags: javascript, function, this

```
// Situation 1 
var a = function A() { 
    this.x = 1;
    var b = function B () {
        this.x = 2;
        console.log('Method B : x = ' + this.x);
    };
    console.log('Method A : x = ' + this.x);
    b();
}
```

When I call a() , my result is

```
Method A : x = 1
Method B : x = 2
```

But if I delete "this.x = 2" as :

```
// Situation 2
var a = function A() { 
    this.x = 1;
    var b = function B () {
        console.log('Method B : x = ' + this.x);
    };
    console.log('Method A : x = ' + this.x);
    b();
}
```

My result will be

```
Method A : x = 1
Method B : x = 1
```

I don't understand why

- In situation 2 : "this" of function B is referenced to "this" of function A

But

- In situation 1 : "this.x" of function A isn't changed when assign "this.x = 2" in function B

My code runs on Chrome v23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, `this.x = 2` is in the definition of function B, it doesn't take place until B is *called*, not when it's defined. Try this version and see:

```
// Situation 3
var a = function A() { 
    this.x = 1;
    var b = function B () {
        this.x = 2;
        console.log('Method B : x = ' + this.x);
    };
    console.log('Method A before B: x = ' + this.x);
    b();
    console.log('Method A after B: x = ' + this.x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason `this.x` is being changed in both `a` and `b` is because they're both referencing the `window` object.
2. I think you're having a misconception with this one; `this.x` *is* being changed after the call to `b`. We can see this if we reverse the calls:

   ```
   b(); // 2
   console.log('Method A : x = ' + this.x); // 2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `b()` like you do, will result in `this` referencing the *global object* (`window` within a browser environment).

That explains your behavior, your're writting basically `window.x = 1;`

Comment: I think when assign "var a = function A()" , create function object A() . Then "this" in function A() reference to object A , but I don't understand why "this" reference to the __global object__ ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call `b()` until after the value of A was printed. Therefore the value of x was 1 and THEN it was changed to 2 by b.

If you call `b()` before printing `a()` the output will be

```
Method A : x = 2
Method B : x = 2
```

As `b()` will first change value then `a()` will log

This is the function

```
var a = function A() { 
this.x = 1;
var b = function B () {
    this.x = 2;
    console.log('Method B : x = ' + this.x);
};
b();
    console.log('Method A : x = ' + this.x);

}
```

​Both a and b reference the window object `window.x`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a special keyword in javascript and it depends on the context. In your case `function B()` is in the context of `function A()`. So if you don't overwrite `this.x` in `function B()` it'll be the value you assigned in `function A()`.